# Change AD password for user on a different domain with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to change the password for user that is on a different domain than the host where I'm doing it from. This is the example code that I have:

```
$domain = 'someADDomain.local'
$userName = 'SomeUser'

$oldPassword = Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt "Enter the account's old password"
$newPassword = Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt "Enter a new password"

Set-ADAccountPassword -Server $domain -Identity $userName -OldPassword $oldPassword -NewPassword $newPassword
```

The issue is that I'm getting "The server rejected the client credentials". The user that needs password changed is only allowed to login to specific servers, not the domain controller.

Is there a way to specify which server to use, in addition to the domain name?

Ref: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bae9fa8f-f602-4533-97fe-9b2bc9bb800d/powershell-how-to-reset-domain-account-password-for-multiple-domains?forum=ITCG

Comment: Does the user requesting the password change have permission to change the password for the other user in the other domain (the error message suggests not)?

Comment: The password change should be requested from the account that needs changed itself and use old/new password.

Comment: Yes, that would be the normal suggestion.

Comment: Basically I have the user and old password and I can RDP to a server 2012 on that domain. My system is on a different domain. The issue is that the AD PowerShell module is not installed on 2012 server and I'm trying to do it from my system, which has it.

Comment: @user1781482, If you can RDP to a Server on a different domain, that doesn't necessarily mean that you are a domain administrator.

Comment: The domains needs to have a trust relationship for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

The current user in the current domain has apparently no permission change the password of the user in the other domain, meaning that you will need to provide other credentials (see `-Credential`) to the [`Set-ADAccountPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-adaccountpassword?view=win10-ps) cmdlet.

Try:

```
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "PlainTextPassword" -AsPlainText -Force $oldPassword
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$domain\$userName", $Password)
Set-ADAccountPassword -Credential $Credential -Server $domain -Identity $userName -OldPassword $oldPassword -NewPassword $newPassword
#                     -----------------------
```

<sub>In the example I presume that the user has permission to change (its own) password, otherwise you will need to supply other credential, e.g. domain administrator credentials of the other domain. This could just be *OtherDomain*\YourAccountName)</sub>

Comment: Should also encrypt the `$newPassword`, then it work for me.